# Testcafe: Unable to select the element even after passing the right selector. Any help will be appreciated?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, testcafe

[image]

```
await t.click(Selector('.select2-search-choice-close'));
```

Can someone help me with what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
await t.click('.select2-search-choice-close');
```

Comment: Tried that as well, but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still relevant for you, try the [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger). With it, you can directly see in the browser which elements the selector matches, or you can automatically generate a selector for the selected element.